# Usecases for JPA 2.1 SynchronizationType.UNSYNCHRONIZED

Tags: jpa, transactions, jta

I am trying to imagine use cases for JPA 2.1 [`SynchronizationType.UNSYNCHRONIZED`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/SynchronizationType.html#UNSYNCHRONIZED). The specification gives the following hint (JRS 338, section 7.6.1):

> In general, it is recommended that a non-JTA datasource be specified for use by the persistence  provider  for  a  persistence  context  of type  `SynchronizationType.UNSYNCHRONIZED` that has not been joined to a JTA transaction in order to alleviate the risk of integrating uncommitted changes into the persistence context in the event that the transaction is later rolled back.

But what does this mean? Do you have any real world examples?